# Select drop down list using python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to select value from the a dropdown list. Basically I want to be able for instance to select PAYOR1 but I cannot find the right class or id . I pasted below the html of the website

```
<div class="Select abyss-selectlist abyss-inputbox Payer-payerSearch-0-2-13 abyss-form--valid has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single"><div class="Select-control"><span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-search-payer-select--value"><div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-search-payer-select--value-item">PAYOR 111</span></div><div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><input id="search-payer-select" aria-activedescendant="react-select-search-payer-select--value" aria-describedby="search-payer-error" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-labelledby="search-payer-label" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 16px; font-family: Frutiger, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 200; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div></div></span><span aria-label="Clear value" class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value"><span class="Select-clear">×</span></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span></div></div>
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54045575/edit) and complete your question.

Comment: it seems that the html code was not posted there.

Comment: oh i see, yes, the code was rendered as html. thanks, i've formatted it.

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce a drop-down-list with that html code. Have you tried using selenium to select the value?